# Probability questions with balls in a vase

Tags: probability

Can anyone help me to solve this exercise ?

> A bag contains six white and four black balls
>
> a) You take two balls out. What is the chance for two white balls ?
>
> b) You take three balls, and you don't replace them. What is the
> chance for two white balls ?
>
> c) You take three times a ball and put it back. What is the chance for
> two white balls now ?

All solutions appreciated. Thanks

My solution

a) 6/10 x 5/9 = 5/15

b) 6/10 * 5/9 * 4/8

c) 6/10 * 6/10 * 6/10

I would like to know is that correct ?

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you have tried. What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: My solution for part a is :

6/10 x 5/9 = 5/15

I would like to know is that correct ?

For part b and c, I dont know how to resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In total we have $10$ balls in which $6$ are white.

The chance for picking first white ball is $6/10$ Now if we take it out we have a total of 9 balls in which 5 are just white so the chance for another white one is $5/9$ which means in total we have $6/10 * 5/9$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: First, thank you so much for your help. It's also my solution for part a. May i know if my approach for part b is correct as following : 

6/10 * 5/9 * 4/8 ?

Comment: Because I don't really understand the question when it's mentioned to not replace the ball.  For question c, the probability of the first ball being white is 6/10. As the ball is replaced and the second picked, the probability of this being white is also 6/10, and also same for the third ball. It's that correct 6/10 * 6/10 * 6/10 ?

Comment: It's not correct, they are asking for 2 white not 3